# ActionBar Styling Debug?

Tags: android, xml, debugging, mobile

So here's my code...

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#196aff</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_gray</item>
    </style>

    <color name="light_gray">#f8f8f8</color>
</resources>
```

And what it's supposed to do is turn the action bar taht shade of blue, which it does...so that's perfectly fine...but as for the `textColor` value, I've tested it both ways:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/light_gray</item>
```

and

```
<item name="android:textColor">#f8f8f8</item>
```

and neither seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `android:textColor` for `android:titleTextStyle`.

Change your custom `ActionBar` Style like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#196aff</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f8f8f8</item>
</style>
```